# Cannot view picture React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I having issue as i am new to web programming. I want to make my logo .svg picture appear, but it shows only the text as a alternative. Maybe someone could help me out. Thank you in advance!

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Nav,
  NavLink,
  Bars,
  NavMenu,
  NavBtn,
  NavBtnLink
} from './NavbarElements';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink to='/'>
          <img src={require('../components/images/DEMOSITE.svg')} alt='logo' />
        </NavLink>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
          <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/services' activeStyle>
            Services
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/contact-us' activeStyle>
            Contact Us
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
          </NavLink>
          {/* Second Nav */}
          {/* <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink> */}
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn>
          <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**How it looks like**

[image]

Comment: Is there any error in the browsers console related to the file path?

Comment: provide width and height in image styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the logo.

```js
import logo from '../components/images/DEMOSITE.svg';
```

```js
<img src={logo} alt='logo' />
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have tried, but in a bit different way

Answer (score 1):

Update this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Nav,
  NavLink,
  Bars,
  NavMenu,
  NavBtn,
  NavBtnLink
} from './NavbarElements';
import Logo from "../components/images/DEMOSITE.svg";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink to='/'>
          <img src={Logo} alt='logo' />
        </NavLink>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
          <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/services' activeStyle>
            Services
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/contact-us' activeStyle>
            Contact Us
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
          </NavLink>
          {/* Second Nav */}
          {/* <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink> */}
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn>
          <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ketan Patel